# R : Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm getting this error.

```
features <- layer_input(shape = c(ncol(dat.X)))
Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument
```

Here is the full code

```
library(keras)
# we fit j =0 with feature matrix dat.X , claims dat$C1 and volumes dat$C0
dat <- Final
dat.X <- dat[-c(12:15)]
dat.Y <- as.matrix( dat$C1 / sqrt ( dat$C0 )) # observed responses
dat.W <- as.matrix( sqrt( dat$C0 )) # volumes used as offsets
q <- 20 # number of hidden neurons

# definition of neural network
features <- layer_input(shape = c(ncol(dat.X)))
net <- features % >%
  layer_dense ( units = q , activation = "tanh") % >%
  layer_dense ( units = 1, activation = k_exp )
```

I expect the code made me a neural network model.

Comment: same issue here, have you solved it?

Comment: Same problem with RStudio on Windows. Any solutions ?